# Customize the entire theme of android app on a single click

Tags: android, themes

I want to change the entire theme of my app on a button click (including toolbar color, background color and font). Can anyone suggest how to do this programatically ?

Comment: you can set the style in onclicklistener

Comment: check this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it and its superb infact : I recently did it 
you just need to know about    android's settheme() method:

So let me first describe whole scenerio :
First you need to add your diffrent theme in style.xml

2>now in shared preference add and map these themes as follows:

```
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String themeName = pref.getString("prefSyncFrequency3", "Theme1");
   if (themeName.equals("Africa")) {
      setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

} else if (themeName.equals("Colorful Beach")) {
//Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
setTheme(R.style.beach);

 } else if (themeName.equals("Abstract")) {
//Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

setTheme(R.style.abstract2);
```

} else if (themeName.equals("Default")) {

```
setTheme(R.style.defaulttheme);
```

}

Now in on click you can have conditional statemnts and you can get theme from shared prefrence:

for more detail refer to this link

[link1](http://programondaspot.blogspot.in/2015/10/implementing-users-choice-themeapply.html)

[link 2](http://programondaspot.blogspot.in/2015/10/implementing-users-choice-themeapply_23.html)

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: The links are really very helpful, I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Tips for exploring .Please upvote and accpet answer if you find it helpful :) happy coding

Comment: I'm having one more query. Is it possible to dynamically change the attributes of colors.xml file or use more than one color files on button click?

Comment: Yes  you can change resource any time using getresource() . .Please upvote and accpet answer if you find it helpful :)

Comment: I don't want to change the resource, but change the value of the color specified by name "my_accent" at runtime as shown:                                            <color name="my_accent">#a39c9c</color>

Comment: Yes you can if you have number of color to choose from  The color must be in color.xml file Please upvote and answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation :(

Comment: @Tips you can always accept answers if you are author :)